Question on a proof in principles of algebraic geometry by Griffiths and Harris
From page 168-170, he tried to prove that the meremorphic function fields $M(V)$ on a smooth projective variety $V\subset \mathbb{P}^{n}$ of dimention k with degree d, is indeed the restriction of rational functions on $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ denote by R(V).
Here is the sketch of the ideas:
1.Projects $V$ onto some linear subspace $\mathbb{P}^{k}$ and show that it is a branched cover.
2.With the notation $\pi^*(R(\mathbb
{P}^{k}))$ as the pull back of rational functions on $\mathbb{P}^{k}$. Show that the tower of fields extensions $\pi^*(R(\mathbb
{P}^{k}))\subset R(V)\subset M(V)$ from $\pi^*(R(\mathbb
{P}^{k}))$ to $M(V)$ has index at most d and the field extension $\pi^*(R(\mathbb
{P}^{k}))\subset R(V)$ has index at least d.
On page 169, he proved that each element in $M(V)$ satisfies a degree d polynomial relation with coefficients in $\pi^*(R(\mathbb
{P}^{k}))$. Then he claimed that by primitive element theorem,  the extension from $\pi^*(R(\mathbb
{P}^{k}))$ to $M(V)$ has index at most d. I don't know how to use the primitive elements theorem at this stage.
As far as I am concerned, this only shows that $\pi^*(R(\mathbb
{P}^{k}))\subset M(V)$ is an algebraic extension. We don't even know if it is finite or separable at all.

The fields have characteristic zero, so all extensions are separable.
Now suppose the field extension $$\pi^*K(\mathbb P^k) \subset \mathfrak M(V)$$
is of degree $> d$ (possibly infinite). If it is infinite, choose an intermediate field
$$\pi^* K(\mathbb P^k) \subset L \subset \mathfrak M(V)$$
finite over $\pi^*K(\mathbb P^k)$ of degree $> d$. Then there exists a primitive element $f \in L$, i.e.
$$L = \pi^*K(\mathbb P^k)[f].$$
But then $f$ has degree $> d$, a contradiction.

All extensions are separable or all algebraic extensions are separable?

@JiangTianshu Yeah, algebraic extensions are enough here. Though one can define separability for non-algebraic extensions, and in characteristic zero all extensions are separable under this definition.
